# Снижает ли nginx производительность приложения?

Tags: nginx, golang, проксирование

У меня 1 хостинг, 2 веб приложения (На языке Go). Решил запустить оба одновременно - на разных поддоменах (один, условно, на `app1.domain.com`, второй на `app2.domain.com`). Мог сделать это путём слияния двух приложений и настройки роутеров в коде, но посчитал, что такое разумнее делать nginx'ом, так как пачкать приложения (наводить костыли?) не хотелось. Всё работет, как нужно, интересует только, насколько снижается производительность/пропускная способность приложений от такой манипуляции?

Comment: Сделайте замеры, сравните и выясните. В чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Нагрузку создаёт не кол-во приложений а кол-во запросов на то или иное приложение, и сервер тут тоже играет определенную роль. Одно приложение с "роутером" будет проигрывать двум отдельным при больших нагрузках практически всегда. У nginx можно и, при больших нагрузках, нужно настроить балансировщик нагрузок.

Comment: @InDevX Так ведь суть в том, что у меня nginx проверяет поддомен запроса перед моим приложением. А без nginx'a была бы та же проверка, только внутри приложения - без нужны во внешних слоях.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov это практический подход к решению вопроса, интересует теоретический. Я до этого "эксперимета" c nginx'ом совсем не был знаком, и не знаю, какие он требует ресурсы, сколько времени его работа занимает между получением запроса и его попаданием в моё приложение

Comment: @Don2Quixote Хоть 100 поддоменов засутьте, будет всё быстрей работать чем одно приложение с роутер. И, правильно говорят, для этого нужны benchmark'и производительности. Тут практика важней теории

Comment: Nginx очень производителен. Будет ли проигрывать по скорости роутеру? Зависит от используемого сервера и роутера (fasthttp router будет быстрее, вероятнее всего), от включенных в сборку nginx модулей, от железа. Но оверхед будет незначителен. В любом случае, не рекомендую работу приложения на грани производительности железа. Если же идет борьба за микротайминги, то лучше провести бенчмарк, благо инструментария хватает:
https://github.com/denji/awesome-http-benchmark